# What is the difference between angular component and React component?

Tags: reactjs, angular8

Can someone explain that how the concept of components is different in Angular 8 and React? According to various tutorials I've watched, it says React components are reusable and can be rendered separately but it happens same in Angular as well. In file directory you have a main app component inside which you can create separate sidenav, header , footer components and use it whenever you like. It's isolated. So where's the difference? I've worked on Angular 8 previously and but new to React.

Comment: In terms of isolation they are similar. That's the definition of "component" and they serve the same purpose. They differ mainly in details and plumbing work. I didn't downvote though. This is not a bad question.

Answer (score 0):

Angular and React are two differente technologies. Angular, a framework, with lots of built-in tools, and React a library (in my humble opinion, i would like to believe that you can call React a framework too) that has a popular rendering structure.

Angular and React components has the same concept, but obviously different implementations.
But for sure you can assume that components are made mainly for Code Reuse and Maintenance.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference with some example? It would be really helpful.